# Using date from React query to filter existing state causing too many re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm using react query to call an api to retreive a list of schedule dates for users to use to update a list of selected dates from a calendar.
However I'm not sure how to do this using react query. Currently the naked setDates is causing too many rerenders because it's not inside eg a useEffect() hook that I would normally use for an api call.  Now I'm using react query I'm not sure where to put it?

```
const SomeDateComponent = ({  }) => {

  const [selectedDates, setSelectedDates] = React.useState<selectedDates>({});
  .....
  
  const { data: existingSchedules } = useExistingScheduleDates(
    startDate,
    endDate,
    userIds.map((agent) => agent.userId),
  );

  
  setDates((selectedDates) => ({ ...selectedDates, ...existingSchedules }))

  return (....)
```

custom Hook:

```
export function useExistingScheduleDates(
  startDate: Date,
  endDate: Date,
  userIds: number[],
): QueryObserverResult<ExistingScheduleDates> {
  return useQuery(
    ['existingSchedules', startDate, endDate],
    () => {
      return apiCall( {
        route: '/schedulesExist',
        query: {
          startDate: format(startDate, dateFormat),
          endDate: format(endDate, dateFormat),
          userId: userIds,
        },
      });
    },
    {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely cannot / should not call a setter function of `useState` *during* render, as this violates a core principle of React that render functions should be pure. What you *can* do is:

- set it in a useEffect

```
const { data: existingSchedules } = useExistingScheduleDates(...)

useEffect(() => {
    setDates(...)
}, [existingSchedules])
```

- set it in the `onSuccess` callback of `useQuery`

```
const { data: existingSchedules } = useQuery(
  'key',
  queryFn,
  {
    onSuccess: data => setDates(...)
  }
)
```

Both of these should work, but the question remains: Why would you need to do that? react-query *is* a state manager per se, so there is really no need to store that additionally in client state. The best way to use react-query is to keep the client state and the server state separated. I would suggest to store the user selection (`selectedDates`) in `useState`, have the server data handled completely by react-query (`existingSchedules`), and combine them in the render function if you need to:

```
const { data: existingSchedules } = useExistingScheduleDates(...)
const [selectedDates, setSelectedDates] = React.useState<selectedDates>({})

const someComputedThing = computeSomeThing(existingSchedules, selectedDates)
```

sorry for the bad naming, I have no idea how `existingSchedules` works together with `selectedDates`, but I hope you get the idea :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I didn't mention that the someComputedThing will be passed down to a child component to be used. (The original user selected dates, will be filtered by the existingSchedules dates - which are dates for which a schedule already exists, so the selectedDates need to be updated with this data (either by using that piece of state or by making a new piece and passed down to the child component). So it looks like the last option you suggested probably won't work?

Comment: Why won’t it work then? You can pass the result if the computation to a child component just fine. If the child component is memoized and you want to pass the same reference down in every render where nothing changed, you can wrap the computation in `React.useMemo`.